# Как пробросить маршрут в локальную сеть?

Tags: маршрутизация

Вся суть вопроса изложена в шапке и на схеме рисунка.
Есть общая сеть компании (global) и в этой сети поднята локалка (local), у которой есть роутер, который имеет адрес как в локальной, так и в глобальной сети. И есть один компьютер в глобальной сети и один в локальной. Мне нужно найти способ достучаться из компа в глобальной до компа в локальной сети. Если честно, то я не совсем понимаю что нужно сделать для этого. По всей видимости в настройках роутера необходимо то ли настроить проброс маршрутов, то ли проброс портов. Не совсем понимаю.

Даже после прочтения ответов здесь, все равно не стало легче.
https://toster.ru/q/472170

Заранее спасибо[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zsrh.png)

Comment: Вообще нужен нат и настройка маршрутов. Какие ip на машинах и на интерфейсах роутера? Какой роутер? какие шлюзы по умолчанию?

Answer (score 1):

Проброс портов.
Для локального компа необходимо установить постоянный (с помощью настройки DHCP роутера) IP-адрес, а потом указать роутеру все нужные порты к этому IP. Либо включить локальный комп в DMZ.
Все обращения будут на IP роутера, а тот уже всё перенаправит куда нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, нужно определиться в каком режиме работает роутер - в режиме трансляции адресов (NAT) или обычном. Ну, еще есть режим моста - но в этом режиме все должно работать из коробки, так что исходя из наличия вопроса я заключаю что у вас не мост.

В обычном режиме вам нужно объяснить каждому компьютеру внешней сети где искать внутреннюю. Иными словами, прописать маршрут: *для отправки пакетов в сеть local (адрес и маска) отправляйте их на адрес ip_global*. Для роутеров во внешней сети этот маршрут нужно прописать статически, прочим хостам его лучше раздать через DHCP-сервер. Разумеется, все это могут сделать лишь админы внешней сети.

В режиме NAT ваш роутер "прячет" всю внутреннюю сеть за одним адресом, поэтому ничего на других хостах прописывать не нужно и админам сообщать - тоже. Но все входящие соединения придется разрешать на роутере вручную (или через UPnP, но если бы UPnP у вас работал - вы бы не задавали вопрос). Это и называется "пробрасывать порты". Для проброса порта вам нужно сообщить вашему роутеру следующую информацию:

- протокол (TCP или UDP)
- внутренний адрес
- внутренний порт
- внешний порт
- *на самом деле можно указать еще и внешний адрес, но чаще всего он только один*

После настройки проброса порта внешние "компьютеры" могут обращаться на конечную точку "внешний адрес роутера:настроенный внешний порт" и будут при этом попадать на конечную точку "настроенный внутренний адрес:настроенный внутренний порт".

---

Подводя итог, получаем следующее:

Если в админ этого всего - вам нужно использовать обычный режим роутера, прописать статический маршрут во внутреннюю сеть на остальных роутерах и настроить отправку маршрута на DHCP-сервере.

Если вы не админ и прячетесь от админов - вам нужно включить NAT на роутере и пробросить порты ко всем внутренним серверам, к которым нужен доступ снаружи.

Если вы не админ, но ни от кого не прячетесь - вам достаточно переключить роутер в режим сетевого моста (bridge).